# python3.*-minimal Error during pip installation in docker build - PermissionError - using VScode

Tags: python, docker

This happens with 20.04 & 22.04 docker images with python3.8-minimal and python3.10-minimal (respectively, these are the only ones I've tried). Images are being built within VScode.
The problem occurs during

```
apt install pip
```

output:

```
    ente#0 136.4 Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4_amd64.deb ...

#0 136.4 Unpacking libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...

#0 136.5 Selecting previously unselected package python3.8-minimal.

#0 136.5 Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4_amd64.deb ...

#0 136.5 Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...

#0 136.6 Setting up libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...

#0 136.6 Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...

#0 136.7 Traceback (most recent call last):

#0 136.7   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 215, in <module>

#0 136.7     sys.exit(main())

#0 136.7   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 207, in main

#0 136.7     compile(filename, doraise=True)

#0 136.7   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 172, in compile

#0 136.7     importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)

#0 136.7   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 186, in _write_atomic

#0 136.7 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-38.pyc.140212054232736'

#0 136.7 dpkg: error processing package python3.8-minimal (--configure):

#0 136.7  installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

#0 136.7 Errors were encountered while processing:

#0 136.7  python3.8-minimal
```

I have tried building a container with nothing in it and running the commands from inside the container.

```
sudo apt install pip
```

and

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

still fail

The output is then:

```
 erl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 215, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 207, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/py_compile.py", line 172, in compile
    importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 186, in _write_atomic
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.8/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-38.pyc.139810610523808'
dpkg: error processing package python3.8-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.8-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.8-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This doesn't seem to be reproducible on other PCs

failing minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install pip -y
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: normally `pip` should be automatically installed in newer versions of Pythons. If it has problem with apt modules then you can try to download file `get-pip.py` and run it - see [pip installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include your Dockerfile and any other source code required for a [mcve]?  You shouldn't usually be installing software inside running containers (it will be lost as soon as the container exits) and you shouldn't need `sudo` in Docker.

Comment: Dockerfile added. It's so simple that I thought it might be unnecessary. Apologies. apt get update and apt get update run fine.

Comment: Dockerfile: 
`FROM ubuntu:20.04 
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y 
RUN apt install python3 -y`
results in the same error so I presume it's a problem with python.
It doesn't seem to be pre-installed in the ubuntu image.

Comment: I've found this forum: https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196 that asks the same question, but I can't understand the answer. I've added a daemon.json file:
`$ cat ../../etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "storage-driver": "vfs"
}
`

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned by others, the problem seems to happen when using the overlay2 storage backend in docker. This isn't limited to the snap, but if you are using the snap then it's the default configuration. To change this in the snap-installed version of docker:

- edit /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json and replace
  "overlay2" with "vfs" for the storage-driver
- run `sudo snap restart docker`

Comment: Note that if you switch from `overlay2` to `vfs` as suggested, you will lose access to those containers you already created with `overlay2`.

Comment: Note also that, as the doc says in https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/ :
The vfs storage driver is intended for testing purposes, and for situations where no copy-on-write filesystem can be used. Performance of this storage driver is poor, and is not generally recommended for production use.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/bug-on-apt-install-permission-denied/100196), the issue was with the snap installation

```
snap remove docker
```

and follow the instructions in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: "snap remove docker" instead