# Permission error while processing python3.6-minimal in docker-compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, permission-denied

I'm trying to run docker-compose up -d with the following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG PKGS
ARG SCRIPTS
ARG EXEC

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server iproute2 iptables inetutils-ping vim nano net-tools dnsutils python3-scapy python3-flask traceroute $PKGS

## ssh ##

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

# exec
RUN eval ${EXEC}

# bin
COPY bin/level* /usr/local/bin/
COPY bashrc /root/.bashrc

# entrypoint
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN sed -i -- "s^# startup scripts^${SCRIPTS}^g" /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

but this error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 143, in compile
    importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 113, in _write_atomic
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-36.pyc.140199285249616'
dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.6-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y openssh-server iproute2 iptables inetutils-ping vim nano net-tools dnsutils python3-scapy python3-flask traceroute $PKGS' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'node1' failed to build : Build failed
```

How do I fix it?

I tried to modify the ubuntu version but nothing happened, I tried to separate every apt-get install and I found out that the packages that raise the error are openssh-server, python3-flask and python3-scapy.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior; if I copy and paste your Dockerfile up to the `RUN apt-get install ...` line, it builds without any errors.

Comment: [python3.*-minimal Error during pip installation in docker build - PermissionError - using VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564830/python3-minimal-error-during-pip-installation-in-docker-build-permissionerro) and [Docker | PermissionError: Errno 13 Permission denied & command returned a non-zero code: 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651585/docker-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-command-returned-a-non) both suggest this can happen if Docker is installed using snap rather than APT.