# Python Devcontainer cannot create venv

Tags: python, docker, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to configure a dev container for work on a repository that is deployed as part of a larger suite of applications. There are some legacy integrations on the wider deployment so the entry point in my code must leverage a src-level venv.

I have been through many frustrating cycles now of where to put the install python3-venv command and none seem to result in having it available to run `python3 -m venv venv` once the container is up.

In the current file layout i get the following error when creating the dev container:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.10-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10-venv'
```

And in other configurations, the container fails to build entirely.

Running the command in the command line after build presents the following:

```
Setting up python3-setuptools-whl (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-pip-whl (22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.10.8-1~22.04) ...
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib2to3/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.pyc.140168036623024'dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--configure):
 installed python3-lib2to3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
 python3-distutils depends on python3-lib2to3 (= 3.10.8-1~22.04); however:
  Package python3-lib2to3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-distutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.10-venv:
 python3.10-venv depends on python3.10-distutils; however:
  Package python3.10-distutils is not installed.
  Package python3-distutils which provides python3.10-distutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.10-venv (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-lib2to3
 python3-distutils
 python3.10-venv
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This led me down a long and winding path of deletion and reinstallation but to no avail.

Help at this stage would be wonderfully appreciated.

**Files for reference**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:ubuntu-22.04

COPY install.sh /tmp/scripts/

RUN sh /tmp/scripts/install.sh 

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

install.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################################
# Set up steps as part of system wide configuration
################################################################################

# Installing AWS CLI
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
./aws/install
rm -rf awscliv2.zip
rm -rf aws
```

postcreate.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################################################
# Set up steps for container post creation (path is: /workspaces/<repo-name>)
################################################################################

add_to_bashrc() {
    echo "$1" >> /home/vscode/.bashrc
}

# # Installing Python venv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install python3.10-venv -y

add_to_bashrc 'alias python="python3"'

source /home/vscode/.bashrc
```

devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python DevContainer",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--shm-size=1g"
    ],
    "containerEnv": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "DEVCONTAINER"
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {
                "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
                "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
                "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
                "files.exclude": {
                    ".coverage": true,
                    ".pytest_cache": true,
                    "__pycache__": true
                }
            },
            "extensions": [
                "donjayamanne.python-extension-pack",
                "GitHub.copilot",
                "VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode",
                "ms-toolsai.jupyter",
                "ms-python.python",
                "KevinRose.vsc-python-indent",
                "vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons",
                "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
                "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker"
            ]
        }
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "bash .devcontainer/postcreate.sh"
}
```

Comment: do you need `sudo apt install python3.10-venv -y` in your dockerfile?

Comment: Does [python3.*-minimal Error during pip installation in docker build - PermissionError - using VScode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72564830/python3-minimal-error-during-pip-installation-in-docker-build-permissionerro) describe your problem?  Also note that [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) has been part of the standard library since Python 3.3, so you probably don't need to separately install it.